# Cannot Resolve Constuctor intent

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent

I am trying to use firebase Messaging Service, but I ended up with the following error.

Cannot resolve constructor ' Intent(firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService, java.lang.Class'

### MyFirebaseMessagingService

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService  {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        //Displaying data in log
        //It is optional
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        //Calling method to generate notification
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

    //This method to generate push notification
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {

        //MainActivity Intent Registration
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        //Take Notification Sound
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        //Generate the Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Notification")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        //Create Push Notification
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot resolve constructor ' Intent(` which line

Comment: Try File->Invalidate caches/restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in you `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Please take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client) also

Comment: Both of the above solutions didn't work for me since I am getting errors like' getActivity()' cannot be resolved and variable 'v' too

Comment: Then try `MyFirebaseMessagingService .this` at place of **this** and **getActivity()**, maybe it will work

Comment: Can you please upload a pic of your logcat

Comment: Thank you, for your response the error got cleared, after updating the dependency version